# How to permanently remove/ban programs from the Start Menu Recent List?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

There are a number of programs which I *always* start using other methods e.g. via a desktop shortcut, therefore these programs are just wasting space in my Start Menu. I can manually delete them by right-clicking -> "Remove from this list", yet no matter how often I remove the offending program, it will still appear into the Recent List the next time I start it, regardless of *how* I start it.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to switch the feature off and add links to the programs you do want there manually. At least this gives you a little more control over what gets displayed.

Right click start and choose "`Properties`", click the "`Start Menu`" tab and uncheck "`Store and display recently opened programs in the start menu`". Then you can drag the links to programs you do use often and open via the start menu into the space that's left behind.

Sorry it's not the answer you were looking for, but at least it gives you some control - even if it's the inverse of what you wanted!